# Passport: access a specific route only if the user is not logged in

Tags: laravel, access-token, laravel-passport, bearer-token, laravel-10

I'm using Passport for a work project.

I have a "generic" token available and thanks to it it is possible to access a specific route without the user having logged in.

For example, to make you understand better, I have the route:

`GET --> /api/products`

So through the use of the generic token it is possible to see the list of all the products.

BUT I NOTICED ONE THING with POSTMAN: if a user logs in they can still access this route.

I don't want a logged in user to be able to access this route, so it is possible to access the above mentioned route ONLY through the generic token, therefore only if the user is actually not logged in.

Is it possible to do this with Passport?

If yes, can someone kindly explain to me how to do it?

Comment: You’re re-inventing the wheel. Passport is OAuth. OAuth (and Passport) already supports issuing tokens that aren’t related to a user, using the _client credentials_ grant type: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `guest` middleware just like `auth` middleware checks to see if the user is logged in the `guest` checks to see if the user is not logged in
so you can use it like this with the guard that it's checking

```
$this->middleware('guest:api');
```

hope it helps

Comment: @mkn-dev but if the user is not logged in can he access the route? Because I DON'T want this

Comment: nope only if he is not logged in with that gaurd he can access the route